# Standalone installation of IBM ACE Developer toolkit

Tags: ibm-app-connect

As far as I can see, the only way to develop for IBM ACE is to install the whole IBM ACE for Developers package, which includes the ACE toolkit.

Is there a way to install just the toolkit? I'm developing against an ACE image in Docker, and I don't want to to have to install ACE locally as well, just to get to the toolkit.